# how can i get direction of mobile

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, augmented-reality

i'm developing an augmented reality application by android 
and i need some information about the location and direction of device from google map in mobile .

how can i get those information , if there's any tutorial explain that .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [LocationManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html) and [LocationListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html) classes. Use it like at Google Developers API Guide:
create a LocationManager class:

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

Create LocationListener with overriding onLocationChanged() method, that calls every time you change location:

```
        // Define a listener that responds to location updates
LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {

        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
          // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
          makeUseOfNewLocation(location);
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
      };
```

Register the LocationListener in LocationManager:

```
    // Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

Notice, onLocationChanged() is called at the first time, when you register it with LocationManager

Comment: thanks for those informations , i'll try :)